# Align div to right, without using float

Tags: html, css, alignment

I want the outcome on the  pictures where the 3 bubbles are underneath each other - however when I do this with float, the third and last element aligns with the second that holds the float. How do I make it float right, without having the 3rd element align?

[image]
[image]

html:

```
<section class="javascript">
    <div class="js-wrapper">
        <h3>JAVASCRIPT</h3>
    </div>  
</section>
<section class="javascript">
    <div class="js-wrapper2">
        <h3>JAVASCRIPT</h3>
    </div>  
</section>
<section class="javascript">
    <div class="js-wrapper3">
        <h3>JAVASCRIPT</h3>
    </div>  
</section>
```

css:

```css
.js-wrapper {
   background-color: #8E8ABC;
   border-bottom-right-radius: 12em;
   border-top-right-radius: 12em;
   width: 40%;
}
.js-wrapper2 {
   background-color: #8AACBA;
   border-bottom-left-radius: 12em;
   border-top-left-radius: 12em;
   width: 40%;
   float: right;
}
.js-wrapper3 {
   background-color: #76B783;
   border-bottom-right-radius: 12em;
   border-top-right-radius: 12em;
   width: 40%;
}
```

Comment: Do u want zig-zag method like 1,3,5,7,.. from left side and 2,4,6,8.. from right side?

Comment: *the third and last element aligns with the second that holds the float* Which one is the third and which one is the last element ? Also when you float an element it is taken out of the document flow, all other element will act as if it's not there, and if it's parent depend on it height/width wise, it will then collapse to `0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `display:inline-block` your child element on section

add `text-align:right` `:nth-child(2n+2)` to your `.javascript` section element

```
.javascript:nth-child(2n+2) {
  text-align:right;
}

.js-wrapper {
    background-color: #8E8ABC;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 12em;
    border-top-right-radius: 12em;
    width: 40%;
    display:inline-block;
}
.js-wrapper2 {
    background-color: #8AACBA;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 12em;
    border-top-left-radius: 12em;
    width: 40%;
    display:inline-block;
}
.js-wrapper3 {
    background-color: #76B783;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 12em;
    border-top-right-radius: 12em;
    width: 40%;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/qgfLnd1s/21/

Comment: Why `2n+2` why not just `2n` ?

Answer (score 1):

Without using float concept..

**css**

```
.javascript:nth-child(2n+2) {
    justify-content: flex-end;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
}
.javascript {
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
}
```

or

```
.javascript {
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: The OP says "without using `float`"

Comment: Your first answer with clearing the floats is the right answer. Why remove it ?

Comment: i know clearing is the right answer. but they wants without using float.. Flex is also the best solution..

Comment: clear:both; is used for clearing the div which means, it cant affect the sibling div style

Comment: This question is so confusing the title says *without using floats* and within the question  *How do I make it float right*, i suggest that you edit your question and include the fix for floats as well